# HTTP ERROR 404 when using Ping Federate with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, ping, pingfederate

I am trying to Authenticate to AWS using Ping Federate. I followed the documentation mentione here "https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/integrations/page/zva1601483297169.html" but I am not able to setup the server.

I am using an HTML Form IdP Adapter but when I try to connect from SP Connection using the SSO Application Endpoint"https://host:port/idp/startSSO.ping?PartnerSpId=urn%3Aamazon%3Awebservices"
I am getting an error
"HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /idp/startSSO.ping. Reason:
Not Found"

Anybody has any idea what could be wrong in the setup? Am I missing something in the configuration or some service is not running?

Answer (score 0):

I verified this and I was using the wrong port while making the request.
We just need to check the port in the run.properties file and make the correct request.